# Reserved word in column name - insert into MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, reserved-words

I have a MySQL database with the word "`group`" in one of the column names.
I can't change this database and column's name; it's not mine.

Table users, columns: `id, name, password, group,` and other.
I need to insert a record into this table. I tried `INSERT INTO users (name, group) VALUES ('John', '9')`, but it's not working because of "`group`".

Can you help me, how to insert a record into this table, please?

Comment: I think some id or password or other may be mandatory.Once check it out.

Answer (score 32):

Try:

```
INSERT INTO users (`name`, `group`) VALUES ('John', '9')
```

Comment: With backticks all is working now :-)

Answer (score 21):

use backticks(`) around column names when you use reserved keywords in query:

```
INSERT INTO users (`name`,`group`) VALUES ('John', '9')
```

Read here:  [Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/keywords.html)

Comment: :) already updated. before you wrote.