# Cant find mySQL request error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

Rediculous but I cant find error in this request

```
SELECT * FROM diploms 
LEFT JOIN student ON diploms.student_id = student.student_id 
LEFT JOIN group ON student.group_id = group.group_id
LEFT JOIN speciality ON group.speciality_id = speciality.speciality_id 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN speciality.name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), speciality.name ASC
```

But SQL says

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'group ON student.group_id = group.group_id LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3

WTH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`group` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped by backticks.

```
SELECT * 
FROM diploms 
LEFT JOIN student ON diploms.student_id = student.student_id 
LEFT JOIN `group` ON student.group_id = `group`.group_id
LEFT JOIN speciality ON `group`.speciality_id = speciality.speciality_id 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN speciality.name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
         speciality.name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not good to use reserved keyword as a table or a column name..
group is a reserved keyword and that's why giving an error, you can use quotes tilt (`) to use it as a table name.

Also you can't use it as column name, see the related post:

[group as a column name in insert command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800075/reserved-word-in-column-name-insert-into-mysql)