# Unable to insert value to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, xmpp

I have installed Prosody and am trying to add users directly to the prosody table instead of prosodyctl command.

```
table structure:
================
    `host` TEXT NULL,
    `user` TEXT NULL,
    `store` TEXT NULL,
    `key` TEXT NULL,
    `type` TEXT NULL,
    `value` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
```

and when I do this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO prosody (host, user, store, key, type, value) VALUES ('mydomain.tld', $user, 'accounts', 'password', 'string', $pass)";
```

I get this error

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near..."

I suspect that certain words are reserved words so I tried using with ' and escaped with \, but it didn't work. Same error. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Am sorry I used ' instead of ` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800075/reserved-word-in-column-name-insert-into-mysql solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "INSERT INTO prosody (host, user, store, key, type, value) VALUES ('mydomain.tld', '$user', 'accounts', 'password', 'string', '$pass')";

Comment: Error: INSERT INTO prosody (host, user, store, key, type, value) VALUES ('mydomain.tld', 'test123', 'accounts', 'password', 'string', '91911111111')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key, type, value) VALUES ('mydomain.tld', 'test123', 'accounts', 'password', 'st' at line 1